# Hibernate- Select First Row from the Group using PARTITION of Oracle

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

Referring to [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group), I want to perform the same thing using *Hibernate(v4.3.7)*. But, not using the *Native SQL*. With a simple HQL, the hibernate can't recognize the keyword **WITH**. Again, when I'm trying to execute the first inner sql part, it is aging unable to recognize the keyword **OVER**. I'm restricted to use hibernate query only to perform this task. So, no *Stored Procedure* or *Function* can be written to return a **cursor** and map it to the entity class. But any alternative SQL or HQL to perform the same thing is also welcome.

Environment info-

1. Oracle 11g r2
2. JPA 2.1
3. JDK 7

Please tell, if any other information is also required.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the native SQL?

Comment: I tried it native sql also. But problem occurred there also with some INVALID CHARACTER error. However my prime aim is not to go for direct native sql. @OldProgrammer